# Return value from scriptmanager in jdk8

Tags: java, java-8, eval

I have been trying the below code

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class ScriptCode {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String code="";
        int y=-1;
        ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        code="if(a<b){return b;}else{return a;}";
        engine.put("a",10);
        engine.put("b",100);
        y=(int)engine.eval(code);
        System.out.println(y);
    }
}
```

I am getting an error saying

```
Caused by: jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ParserException: <eval>:1:8 Invalid return statement
if(a<b){return b;}else{return a;}
```

I am not able to resolve this issue. The issue is that in my usecase, the 'code' variable will have some rules, which will return something. I know how to do it without returning, but I am unable to return some value from the code. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

You should declare a function, then execute it, in order to get the results

```
engine.eval("function max(a,b) { if(a<b){return b;} return a;}");
engine.put("a",10);
engine.put("b",100);
int y = (int)engine.eval("max(a,b)"); // will return function result
```

or assign the result to a variable, then read it

```
engine.put("a",10);
engine.put("b",100);
engine.eval("c= a<b? b: a;"); // assign result to a variable
int y = (int) engine.get("c"); // read the value
```

You had an error, because your return statement was not inside of any function, thus return would not be valid. eval is similar as developer tool console in any browser. You need to declare either a function or an variable.

Answer (score 1):

according to [this](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/5399) question you need to write the value you want to return in last row, without `return` keyword. Your example would look like this (with help variable `max`)

```
String code="";
int y=-1;
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
code="if(a<b){" +
        "max = b" +
        "}else{" +
        "max = a" +
        "} " +
        "max";
engine.put("a",10);
engine.put("b",100);
y=(int)engine.eval(code);
System.out.println(y);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't return without being inside a function, easy enough to solve; you can define a JavaScript function and invoke it from Java. Like,

```
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
String code = "function f(a,b) { if(a<b){return b;}else{return a;}}";
engine.eval(code);
Invocable invocable = (Invocable) engine;
int y = (int) invocable.invokeFunction("f", 10, 100);
System.out.println(y);
```

Outputs

```
100
```